# Extract a binary BSP from a cooked CE image

Tags: windows-ce

I'd like to know if it's possible to extract a binary BSP from a cooked CE image. Obviously I know that you cannot decompile the BSP back into its original form, but all I want to do is change the contents of the userland using the catalog items selector in the platform builder. Is this possible?

Comment: Show us some pseudo code, an hint, a start, something to work with, something you already tried

Comment: I don't know what to give you here. I can't give you pseudo code or a hint because I don't even know if what I want to do is even possible. That's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BSP contains sourcecode to boot the system and drivers that are not generic/cross-platform. This is then compiled into binaries and finally the image file is generated. This image file contains the bootable kernel but also a built-in filesystem (the /Windows folder).

If I understand you right, you want to unpack the image, change the content of the built-in filesystem and then pack it up again. This shouldn't be too difficult, but I don't think you will find support for that in PB, so it will require a bit of manual work both for finding the files and the according registry defaults. In addition, adding and removing features might change the cost of your license for the resulting image.

Why can't you just generate a different image? Alternatively, why not simply add the additional software outside the image?

Comment: Thanks for this. It's pretty much the answer I expected but thanks all the same. We're not able to adjust the image because the sources were lost or deleted before my time, and I don't have sufficient time to recreate the entire BSP. I'll look at doing this manually, as we'd like the software to survive a hard-reset without using a memory card or similar.

Comment: It's not even that simple.  Much of the BSP is OAL code that gets compiled into places like coredll.dll and then all of that is fixed up and build time.  I don't know that there's really any way to "unpack" coredll back to the constituent components.  It's akin to taking a loaf of bread and trying to get flour and yeast back out.

Comment: True, really getting the BSP out of the image is futile. However, the OP doesn't seem to need that but only to "change the contents of the userland", for which there is at least some hope that it's not in the kernel or coredll.